# List of Python Objects from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

What I want to do is take a data frame and turn each data frame row into a Python object namely RawData class presented. Dataframe contains 10^5 - 10^6 rows.

```
# Each row represents one RawData object
class RawData():
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True
    currency = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content_id = models.TextField(blank=True)

@classmethod
def create_by_itertuples(cls, item):
    # item is namedtuple. converted to dict
    row = item._asdict()
    return (cls, row['Labels'], row['Currency'], row['Content_Id'])

@classmethod
def create_by_iterrows(cls, row):
    return (cls, row['Labels'], row['Currency'], row['Content_Id'])

@classmethod
def create_by_vectorization(cls, Labels, Currency, Content_Id):
    // How to proceed?
```

I have tried iterrows and itertuples.

```
# sample dataframe
# initialize list of lists
data = [['T-Series', 'BDT', 'UX25437'], 
        ['Dragons Den', 'EUR', 'UF5432'], 
        ['A-Train', 'USD', 'GH5342']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Labels', 'Currency', 'Content_Id'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index)
    r = RawData.create(row)
    listofrows.append(r)
```

I did the same thing with itertuples which provided much better performance.

```
for item in df.itertuples():
   listofrows.append(RawData.create(row))
```

With the number of rows in mind, I am now trying NumPy vectorization. But having a hard time returning a list of objects from ndarrays.

```
listofrows = (RawData.create( df[''].to_numpy(), df['property2'].to_numpy(),
 df['property3'].to_numpy()).to_list()
```

If in create() I have to iterate over the arrays, I figure there's no advantage of doing vectorization. Can this be improved by vectorization? Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am following [this article](https://mlabonne.github.io/blog/iterating-over-rows-pandas-dataframe/).

Edit: As vectorization is allowed only for primitives, are there any better ways for such a operation?

Comment: Please provide details on the "object" you want to create and a reproducible example

Comment: not sure you need to use `iterrows` or `itertuples`.  

I think you may get something close to the structure you want from `listrows = df[['property1', 'property2', 'property3']].to_numpy()`.

You will have an array of the rows.

Comment: Your question is still incomplete/unclear, you don't provide a reproducible example of data and you have many `create` functions that are unused. Also in your `itertuples` example you use the variable `item` to collect items but then reference the undefined `row` in the loop

Comment: As an aside, why are you doing `# item is namedtuple. converted to dict`?? Why not just use `item` as is?

Comment: "I am now trying NumPy vectorization." You cannot really vectorize the creation of Python objects. Vectorization in numpy implies you are working on primitive numeric types (or structured dtypes), *not* python objects.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df["obj"] = df.apply(lambda row: (row["property1"], row["property2"], row["property3"]), axis=1)
```

Or if there is complex logic involved which can't be fit in one line, then create a function and call in place of `lambda` .